# how to prevent call on OnValidate() when running game

Tags: unity

I need `OnValidate()` to be called only when I am designing my level (placing game objects at their respective positions and setting properties before running the project). But I don't want it to be called when I run the project. I can manually comment it out, but that will take a lot of time, since I have several `OnValidate()` calls. How can this be done, if it is possible?

Comment: Maybe you can use : if ! ( Application.isPlaying) ..... into OnValidate()